# Simple Angular route change animation not working on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic slide-in slide-out animation for each route on enter and leave within my AngularJS app.

The animations work perfectly on desktop, although bug out on mobile. They do seem to work within the dev tools emulator though.

I have tracked it down to having something to do with the views position not being set correctly with the `absolute` position. Seems as if when a new view is loaded, they both exist within the page, hence making the pages width twice and large until the old view is unloaded and removed. I then tried a position `relative` on the parent container, although no luck.

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://embed.plnkr.co/KjEHNZ6ZZ8IAwMPuOu1U/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` for the container of your views, in the case of your plnkr, it's the `<body>`

Comment: What about in cases where there is a vertical scroll going down the page? I tried using just `overflow-x: hidden`, although that just removed my vertical scroll altogether and did not fix the animation problem anyways.

Comment: have you tried setting your `overflow-y` to 'auto` or 'scroll`? ahh, ok, hmmm

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Just a simple `overflow-y` to `auto`. I had it on a different div container, but moved it to the body and now it's working :)